# Using VB6 event in VB.net e.g AfterColUpdate (DataGridView event)

Tags: vb.net, vb6, datagridview, vb6-migration

I am doing VB6 to VB.NET conversion.
I am facing problem in using below DataGridView events  in VB.NET :

1. `AfterColUpdate`
2. `AfterDelete`
3. `BeforeDelete`

Please help.

Comment: These events are not supported by datagridview in .net. Use CellValueChanged instead of AfterColUpdate.

Comment: @Romil : I am looking for alternate events with I can use in place of above event.As you suggested 'CellValueChanged ' for AfterColUpdate). Thanks.Can you give me alternate events for other two.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These events are not supported by datagridview in .net.

Use `CellValueChanged` instead of `AfterColUpdate`, `UserDeletedRow` for `AfterDelete`, `UserDeletingRow`  for `BeforeDelete`.

Comment: Thanks.I will check.One more event : BeforeColUpdate. I didn't found any event for it.